# A doubt in Atiyah-Macdonald's "Introduction to Commutative Algebra"

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

"Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah-Macdonald says the following:

> Let $G_n$ be the subgroup containing elements of order $p^n$ in the group $\Bbb{Q/Z}$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$. Here $p$ is a prime number. Then $G_1\subset G_2\subset G_3\subset\dots$

I can understand that $G_1$ would be such a subgroup. But how would $G_2$ be a subgroup where every element is of order $p^2$? The elements in $G_2$ would be $\overline{0},\overline{1/p^2},\overline{2/p^2},\dots$ Then $\overline{p/p^2}$ would be of order $p$, and not $p^2$!

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It's a bit of sloppy language in A-M's part, perhaps. There is no subgroup that contains only elements of order $p^n$, since $0$ has to be in any subgroup. There is a subgroup *generated* by the elements of order $p^n$.

Comment: In general, when a mathematician says "the subgroup containing $S$," where $S$ is a subset of $G$, they either mean $S$ is a subgroup, or it means they are talking about the subgroup generated by $S$...

Comment: One last comment: It is often a good idea to give the edition of the book you are using, since sometimes things get fixed or there are public errata around.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews- There seems to be no mention of an edition anywhere in the book.

Comment: and "subgroup containing elements of order..." is as sloppy a way to describe a group as one can expect.

Comment: @Ayush, what page, chapter and section is that in A-M?

Comment: @DonAntonio- Chapter 6 (Chain Complexes). End of pg 74. Point 3

Comment: Often, just the year of publishing is a good substitute for "edition."

Comment: **A-M didn't say what you wrote!** The book says: "Let $G$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ consisting of all elements whose order is a
power of $p$, where $p$ is a fixed prime. Then $G$ has exactly one subgroup $G_n$ of order $p^n$ for each $n\ge 0$..."

Comment: @user26857- Do you mean to say that $G_2$ is a group of order $p^2$ consisting of elements of order $p$? Could you kindly outline such a group? What kinds of elements would it contain?

Comment: @user26857- Apologies, I misunderstood the statement....twice. $G_n$ need not contain elements only of order $p^n$. It is a subgroup of order $p^n$ comprising of elements whose order is any power of $p$.